# Cannot launch Karabiner Elements

Tags: karabiner

When I attempt to launch Karabiner Elements, it says the application cannot be launched.

In the past I was able to resolve it by downloading the installer again, and running it. I tried doing that but didn't that this time, but it didn't work.

When I attempt to delete the app in the Applications folder in finder, it says that the item is locked and can't be deleted.

I can no longer see the UI of Karabiner elements, nor use my keyboard mappings.

Answer (score 2):

I tried different iterations of these steps, but the one that ultimately ended up working was:

1. [Uninstall](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html) the app via command line (since GUI wasn't launching):

   ```
   sudo '/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/uninstall_core.sh'
   ```
2. Reinstall the app via the installer. Do not launch Karabiner Elements.
3. Restart the computer.
4. While it's restarting, hold down command+option+p+r to [reset the PRam](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063). Let go after the Apple logo appears the second time.
5. Launch Karabiner Elements.